# phpMyAdmin - Error | The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu OS 14.04 LTS. After I run **sudo apt-get dist-upgrade**(*run this command because I unable to download and update it when the os ask me*) I cannot open phpmyadmin again. **Before that I can open it normally.**

I am using **PHP Version 7.0.4-5**, **phpmyadmin 4.5.5.1** With phpmyadmin 
I downloaded it from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ and then move to **/var/www/html**.

I have enabled

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll     
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

and restart apache2 still not work. And when I run **php-m** and phpinfo() also cannot find **mbstring**.

Please help solve this problem. Really thankful for help me.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yey :) I have solved it!!!!
Just run this

```
    sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
    sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

and then `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: I solved it using `sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring`. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks @Doo Doo We must need to restart server to see the effect!

Comment: This fixed my issue! I am using Ubuntu 16.04 under a DigitalOcean droplet. This should fix your issue if you are running into this situation.

Answer (score 12):

I solved with :

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.*
sudo apt-get install php7.*-mbstring
```

and then -

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: unable to find the package by regex :(

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by these commands :

```
 sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
 sudo apt-get install php-gettext
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all as you're using Ubuntu, it supports .so files windows has .dll files

Open terminal and try installing below :

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me but the following. After I tried all methods, I ran Synaptic Package Manager program and manually forced to install all programs with names beginning from (all versions of):

- mcrypt
- mbstring

Then I restarted apache2 in the terminal by

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

and that’s it: phpMyAdmin works after these steps.

Answer (score 1):

I am using CentOS release 6.9 (Final) 
tried 
1.yum install php-mbstring
2.yum install php-gettext
3.service httpd restart
and working fine now

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just FYI...the answer you submitted was to a very old question (over 2 years old) that already has an accepted answer. You might want to check out unanswered questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

Comment: Thanks. This is the only answer here for Amazon Linux since it uses yum instead of apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. I reconfigure phpmyadmin and install php7.0 modules. I post my solution on this post:  https://askubuntu.com/a/764254/212315

Answer (score 0):

I initially tried to use `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext`
however this returned an error where it automatically aborted, (which maybe linked to my available memory on a Raspberry pi 3 B+).

Instead I ran `sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring` (note to amend code with your php version. If unsure first check this via; `php --version`). This should now setup and create config file.

Finally run; sudo service apache2 restart. Reload web address and you should have access to php admin.

Although in some instances you may incur a follow up error; "mysqli extension is missing".

In this case type; `sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysql` and then; `sudo service apache2 restart`
and.....NOW you should have access to phpadmin.